# RSA.Verify issues in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core

I'm working with a 3rd party who sends me a certificate via a byte array.  They send me 3 strings in an XML document that include, x509Data, SignatureValue, and DigestValue(for debugging).

They want me to validate that the SignatureValue is valid using the certificate public key contained in the x509Data cert.  I'm populating the cert fine but when I try to Verify, it always returns false.

Here is my code:

```
byte[] SignatureValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.SignatureValue);
byte[] x509DataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.x509Data);
byte[] DigestValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.DigestValue);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(x509DataBytes);
using (RSA RSA = (RSA)cert.PublicKey.Key)
{
    bool a = RSA.VerifyData(x509DataBytes, SignatureValueBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

Signature.* is the string coming from the XML file.  Can some kind soul point out where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as written, is trying to verify that `SignatureValueBytes` is a signature that signed `x509DataBytes` using RSASSA-PKCS1-SHA256.

Assuming you got the RSASSA-PKCS1-SHA256 part right, you probably want to use `VerifyHash` and `DigestValueBytes` instead of `VerifyData` and `x509DataBytes`.  (You also want to use `cert.GetRSAPublicKey()` instead of `cert.PublicKey.Key`)

```
byte[] SignatureValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.SignatureValue);
byte[] x509DataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.x509Data);
byte[] DigestValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Signature.DigestValue);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(x509DataBytes);
using (RSA RSA = cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
{
    bool a = RSA.VerifyHash(DigestValueBytes, SignatureValueBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

Comment: White spaces and newline matters? In my XML SignatureValue is on multiple lines, Also, <KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate> is multi lines?